# C++ Initialise array size after declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is for an assignment so I'm restricted to what operators, etc. I can use. I can't use vectors.

My program takes an input of a maze and solves it.

Originally I had this array bring used:

```
Crumb* crumbs[MAX_SIZE];
```

The maze was originally a fixed-sized and we, therefore, could initialise the crumbs array to it's max possible size. However, now we have to change it so that the maze is dynamically sized and we also have to dynamically assign memory using the 'new' operator (and delete).

We've been told to change the above code to:

```
Crumb** crumbs;
```

I'm now not really sure how to fix up my class to use this new declaration. The below code is my full class that handles the array (which is an array of Crumb objects);

```
Trail::Trail() {
}
Trail::~Trail() {
}

int Trail::size() {
   return length;
}

Crumb* Trail::getPtr(int i) {
   return crumbs[i];
}

void Trail::addCopy(Crumb* t) {
   crumbs[length] = new crumb(*t);
   length++;
}

bool Trail::contains(int x, int y) {
   bool contains = false;

   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
      if(crumbs[i]->getX() == x && crumbs[i]->getY() == y){
         contains = true;
      }
   }
   return contains;
}

bool Trail::containsStale(int x, int y) {
   bool contains = false;

   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){

      if(crumbs[i]->getX() == x && crumbs[i]->getY() == y){
         if(crumbs[i]->isStale() == true){
            contains = true;
         }
      }
   }
   return contains;
}
```

I've handled reading the input and the size, so at this point of calling on this class I know the size of the maze, I'm just not sure how to now intialise and use the crumbs array.

Comment: You're not doing enough.   `addCopy()` blindly does `crumbs[length] = new crumb(*t);`.   This creates a new instance of `crumb` but does not magically increase the number of elements in `crumbs`.   If the actual number of elements allocated for `crumbs` is `length` then accessing `crumbs[length]` gives undefined behaviour - it doesn't magically increase the number of valid elements of `crumbs`.    Incrementing `length`, which this function also does,  also does NOT change the number of valid elements of `crumbs`.

Comment: Also, seriously consider whether you need an array of pointers (`crumb *`) versus an array of `crumb`.    C++ is not a language with reference semantics (like Java or whatever other language you are used to), and doesn't require every object to be initialised using `new` - in fact, doing so is both unnecessary and causes a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

> C++ Initialise array size after declaration?

You cannot. The size of an array variable must be known when declared.

Simply allocate a dynamic array instead. Simplest solution is to use `std::vector`, but if you cannot use it, then implement your own vector class.